# Is the use of "for i := x to y" well defined behaviour, if x > y?

Tags: delphi, for-loop

The intuitive answer would be that the loop is never entered. And this seems to be case in all tests I could come up with. I'm still anxious and always test it before entering the loop.

Is this necessary?

Comment: No, the precondition of entering for loop `for i:= x to y` is x must be less or equal than y, this is handled by your language interpreter at runtime automatically whatever language you use.

Comment: At some stage you have to trust the compiler. This one is more than 20 years old and this is essential functionality.

Comment: Or read the documentation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not necessary.

[The documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#For_Statements) clearly states :

> **for** counter := initialValue **to** finalValue **do** statement
>
> or:
>
> **for** counter := initialValue **downto** finalValue **do** statement
>
> ...
>
> If *initialValue* is equal to *finalValue*, *statement* is executed exactly once.  If *initialValue* is greater than *finalValue* in a **for...to** statement, or less than *finalValue* in a **for...downto** statement, then *statement* is never executed.

There is no need for anxiety.

If we want to examine further what happens, let's make a few examples.  Consider first :

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 2 to 1 do WriteLn(i);
end.
```

This produces a compiler hint:

> [dcc32 Hint] Project1.dpr(6): H2135 FOR or WHILE loop executes zero times - deleted

So the compiler will simply throw away a loop with constants that produce no loop iterations.  It does this even with optimizations turned off - no code is produced for the loop at all.

Now let's be a bit more clever :

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
var
  i, j, k : integer;
begin
  j := 2;
  k := 1;
  for i := j to k do WriteLn(i);
end.
```

This actually compiles the loop.  The output is as below:

```
Project1.dpr.8: for i := j to k do WriteLn(i);
004060E8 A1A4AB4000       mov eax,[$0040aba4]   {$0040aba4 -> j = 2}
004060ED 8B15A8AB4000     mov edx,[$0040aba8]   {$0040aba8 -> k = 1}
004060F3 2BD0             sub edx,eax           {edx = k - j = -1} 
004060F5 7C2E             jl $00406125          {was k-j < 0? if yes, jmp to end.}
004060F7 42               inc edx               {set up loop}
004060F8 8955EC           mov [ebp-$14],edx
004060FB A3A0AB4000       mov [$0040aba0],eax
00406100 A118784000       mov eax,[$00407818]       {actual looped section}
00406105 8B15A0AB4000     mov edx,[$0040aba0]
0040610B E8E8D6FFFF       call @Write0Long
00406110 E8C3D9FFFF       call @WriteLn
00406115 E8EECCFFFF       call @_IOTest
0040611A FF05A0AB4000     inc dword ptr [$0040aba0] {update loop var}
00406120 FF4DEC           dec dword ptr [ebp-$14]
00406123 75DB             jnz $00406100             {loop ^ if not complete}
Project1.dpr.9: end.
00406125 E88EE1FFFF       call @Halt0
```

So, the very first thing a loop does is to check whether it needs to execute at all.  If the initial is greater than the final (for a **for..to** loop) then it skips straight past it entirely.  It doesn't even waste the cycles to initialize the loop counter.

Answer (score 1):

There are some edge-cases in which you may be surprised to discover that the code ***does unexpectedly*** enter the loop. And still other cases where you may be tempted to pre-check whether to call the loop. But before I get into those details, I want to try impress on you the importance of ***not*** pre-checking your loop with an `if` condition.

Every line of code, no matter how easy to understand *draws attention*. It's more to read and more to confirm is correct. So if it's not important, or if it's technically redundant: it's best left out.

A for loop is conceptually translated as follows:

1. Initialise loop index to starting value.
2. If iteration constraint is valid (e.g. Index <= EndValue in case of forward loop):

   - Perform iteration (code within loop block/statement)
   - Perform loop control operations (increment loop index)
   - Repeat 2
3. Otherwise continue at first instruction after loop.

The way in which Step 2 is checked, makes an extra `if` condition before the loop completely redundant.

So if you (or another developer) is later maintaining code with a redundant `if` condition, they're left to wonder:

- Is the line correct?
- It seems redundant; is there a special condition it's trying to handle?
- If it currently serves no purpose, perhaps it was intended to prevent calling the loop on a different condition?

In simple case, redundant lines of code can create some confusion. In more complex cases, they can result in whole new sections of irrelevant code being developed; that tries to cater for irrelevant scenarios implied by legacy redundant code.

> **Recommendation**: Stamp out redundant code as much as possible. *Including* redundant pre-checks for "should the loop execute at all".
>   The most important benefit of stamping out redundant code is that: it **correctly** *draws attention* to peculiar cases whenever special handling actually ***is required***.

---

There are 2 potential pitfalls, and the first is the more dangerous one as it deals with implicit type conversion. So it may not always be easy to detect. The following code was tested on rextester using fpc, but I have verified the same issue on Delphi 2007 / 2009 in the past.

```
//fpc 2.6.2

program UnexpectedForIteration;
{$MODE DELPHI}
{ Ensure range-checking is off. If it's on, a run-time error
  prevents potentially bad side-effects of invalid iterations.}
{$R-,H+,W+}

var
  IntStart, IntEnd, IntIndex: Integer;
  UIntStart, UIntEnd, UIntIndex: Cardinal;
  IterCount: Integer;
begin
  Writeln('Case 1');
  IntStart := High(Integer) - 1;
  IntEnd := -IntStart;
  UIntStart := Cardinal(IntStart);
  UIntEnd := Cardinal(IntEnd);
  {This gives a clue why the problem occurs.}
  Writeln('From: ', IntStart, ' To: ', IntEnd);
  Writeln('From: ', UIntStart, ' To: ', UIntEnd, ' (unsigned)');

  Writeln('Loop 1');
  IterCount := 0;
  for IntIndex := IntStart to IntEnd do Inc(IterCount);
  Writeln(IterCount);

  Writeln('Loop 2');
  IterCount := 0;
  { The loop index variable is a different type to the initial &
    final values. So implicit conversion takes place and:
    IntEnd **as** unsigned is unexpectedly bigger than IntStart }
  for UIntIndex := IntStart to IntEnd do Inc(IterCount);
  Writeln(IterCount, ' {Houston we have a problem}');

  Writeln();
  Writeln('Case 2');
  UIntStart := High(Cardinal) - 2;
  UIntEnd := 2;
  IntStart := Integer(UIntStart);
  IntEnd := Integer(UIntEnd);
  {This gives a clue why the problem occurs.}
  Writeln('From: ', UIntStart, ' To: ', UIntEnd);
  Writeln('From: ', IntStart, ' To: ', IntEnd, ' (signed)');

  Writeln('Loop 3');
  IterCount := 0;
  for UIntIndex := UIntStart to UIntEnd do Inc(IterCount);
  Writeln(IterCount);

  Writeln('Loop 4');
  IterCount := 0;
  { The loop index variable is a different type to the initial &
    final values. So implicit conversion takes place and:
    UIntStart **as** signed is unexpectedly less than UIntEnd }
  for IntIndex := UIntStart to UIntEnd do Inc(IterCount);
  Writeln(IterCount, ' {Houston we have a problem}');
end.
```

The output is as follows:

```
Case 1
From: 2147483646 To: -2147483646
From: 2147483646 To: 2147483650 (unsigned)
Loop 1
0
Loop 2
5 {Houston we have a problem}

Case 2
From: 4294967293 To: 2
From: -3 To: 2 (signed)
Loop 3
0
Loop 4
6 {Houston we have a problem}
```

> In many cases the problem is resolved by ensuring the same types are used for `loopIndex`, `initialValue` and `finalValue`. As this means there won't be an implicit type conversion, and the loop will reliably iterate as the *`initialValue`* and *`finalValue`* would suggest.
>   It would be easier if the compiler emits appropriate warnings for implicit type conversion in **for** loops. Unfortunately fpc didn't; I don't recall whether Delphi 2007/2009 does; and have no idea whether any recent versions do.
>
> However, the preferred approach would be to favour container iteration syntax (pushing responsibility for 'correct' iteration on the enumerators). E.g.: `for <element> in <container> do ...;`. This should not iterate empty containers provided the enumerator's methods are implemented correctly.
>
> The only time I'd say a pre-check is worth considering is:
>
> - when `for in` is not feasible for some reason
> - and the loop index needs to be zero-based
> - and support large unsigned integers (High(Integer) < index < High(Cardinal))
> - because this leaves no space for a reliable sentinel less than all possible initial values.
> - Even in this case, consider using an `Int64` loop index instead of `if (initialValue <= finalValue) then for ...`.

---

The second pitfall involves what I would in any case consider to be a design flaw. So the problem can be avoided entirely by rather being aware of this design consideration. It is demonstrated in code that looks as follows:

```
if Assigned(AnObject) then
  for LIndex := 0 to AnObject.Count - 1 do ...;
```

In this case the `if` condition may in fact be necessary as a result of dubious design. Certainly, if `AnObject` hasn't been created, you do not want to access its `Count` property/method. But the dubious aspect of the design is the fact that you're uncertain whether `AnObject` exists. Yes, you may have employed a lazy-initialisation pattern. But it doesn't change the fact that in the above code, there's no way to differentiate between: "zero iterations" because `AnObject` doesn't exist or because `AnObject.Count = 0`.

I'd like to point out that when code has many redundant `if Assigned(AnObject) then` (or similar) lines, it leads to one of the problems I described in section 1. Local code caters for 2 possibilities. And by extension, client code also caters for 2 possibilities. And by induction, this problem eventually leaks throughout the code-base.

> The solution is to first and foremost limit the cases where existence of `AnObject` is uncertain.
>
> - It's much easier to ensure an empty object with `Count = 0` is guaranteed to be created (typically only affecting a small number of places in code).
> - It's far more work to deal with the ripple effects of a large number of places where the object might not exist yet; yielding 2 possible states and code paths.
>
> If lazy-initialisation is required, try to ensure the code surface where existence is optional is kept as small as possible.

Comment: In all of your examples the loops work exactly as they're supposed to.  This isn't a pitfall to do with loops, it's entirely related to invalid typecasting and it's a bug no matter the context you find it in.

Comment: @J... Clearly you missed the whole point of that section of my answer. (And perhaps ignored the rest?) E.g. In Loop 2 `IntStart = 2147483646` and `IntEnd = -2147483646`; so you would not ***expect*** the loop to execute. But it will due to ***implicit*** typecasting. _Yes that behaviour is well-defined; but it's clearly **unintuitive**._ And more's the shame that at least one compiler doesn't even emit a warning.

Comment: Well, if you insist on compiling with range and overflow checks turned off, at least during testing and debugging, then you're basically telling the compiler explicitly that you *know* you're doing something stupid and you want it to happen anyway.  Calling the result "unexpected" in that case is a bit disingenuous.

Comment: @J... Perhaps you missed that fact that I use the "invalid typecasting" purely to explain ***why*** the problem occurs. Loop 2 iterates using the `Integer` from and to variables, which means it **should not enter** the loop. But because they _lop index_ is `Cardinal`, they are implicitly type-cast, and code ***does*** enter the loop.

Comment: Yes, and loop 2 would raise an `ERangeError` exception if you hadn't disabled it.

Comment: @J... I don't insist range-checking be turned off. It is required to observe the problem (but imho unexpected Range Errors at peculiar edge-cases are still undesirable). But more importantly because many developers have the strange notion that there's a real benefit to always turning range-checking off in production code - these edge cases are a **very real** possibility. What's really disingenuous is pretending that you would "expect" `for LoopIndex :=  0 to -1 do` to enter the loop.

Comment: It doesn't enter the loop if range checking is enabled.  The first thing the loop does with the implicit typecast is to load `IntStart` and `IntEnd` and test them for sign - if any are negative it raises an exception.  The loop is only entered if you've disabled that sanity check.  Again, this has nothing to do with loops - these types of errors can show up **anywhere** in code.

Comment: @J... The whole point of the second section of my answer is that there ***are cases*** where the loop behaves unexpectedly. It's not advisable to turn range-checking off. But it is a valid thing to do. (In the same way it's not advisable to use **with**.) _Given OP's question specifically stating he couldn't come up with a negative test case, I'd say my answer is perfectly justified._ (And it certainly doesn't detract from your thorough answer.)

Comment: @J... Many implicit typecasts emit appropriate warnings. I do not recall having seen any on the for loops in Delphi 2007 & 2009. Unfortunately, I don't have any version of Delphi installed atm. So I cannot confirm if this is still the case.

Comment: @J... Final thought. (_because I really don't have time to waste arguing with you about whether others may benefit or learn from my warning of this peculiar edge-case_): You can _even seem to be type-consistent and experience the error_. `for UIntIndex := UIntStart to UIntCount-1 do` and not even turn range-checking off to get the error.... why ***because range-checking is off by default***

Comment: Yes, there could be warnings here, I agree.  It's clearly a silly idea to use an unsigned loop counter when you're using signed limits - imo, this is simply a bug and there's no good reason to ever do this.  That said, it's **always** a good idea to make checks when converting between signed and unsigned values, and to make sure you're not overflowing.  Again, nothing to do with loops.  You can either let the compiler do this for you (turning on checks) or do it yourself.  Failing to make this check here is an error, but I have to stress that it's not the loop that is failing.